# Restrict Object Type's path at CompileTime

Tags: java, scala, types

Let's say we have following:

```
interface Container

package com.one
class ContainerImplOne extends Container

package com.two
class ContainerImplTwo extends Container
```

We have many implementations which inherits from Container but reside in different packages. If we have a function which takes a type Container:

```
def compute(c: Container): Unit
```

We won't know if the passed in object is from package com.one or com.two. Is there a way to restrict compute function to take Container instance from package two? In other words is there a way to restrict type to be from com.Two.*? Can we do this either in Java or Scala?

Comment: @DavisBroda No, its not the same question. Significance here is not the name of concrete type but they inherit from the same interface and function take the type of interface. But both implementations are defined in different packages. I updated impl to have different names.

Comment: then make it take containerImplTwo, rather than container, and your problem is solved. If you only want one implementation, then why are you using the interface to begin with?

Comment: No, there are many implementations of type Container and it can come from either packages.

Comment: If that's the case, update the question with that info. But if you can edit the source of package two, I may have an idea.

Comment: @DavisBroda We are third party library so we can't.

Comment: What exactly is the use case for this? Are you trying to access functionality only available in certain implementations or something? why disallow certain classes that meet the contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (if you really, really, really need to; if I ever saw a library which did that except maybe to work around known bugs in `com.one`, I'd try to avoid it at all costs):

```
def compute(c: Container): Unit = {
  if (c.getClass.getPackage.getName == "com.two") {
    ...
  } else {
    // do nothing, or throw an exception, etc.
  }
}
```

You can modify it to support classes extending a class in `com.two` as well.

This fails at run-time and not at compile-time, you could make a macro which would fail at compile-time instead.

Comment: We ended up doing exactly that.